# BigQuery Missing Events when the intraday table converts to a regular table

Tags: google-bigquery

For our project we use Firebase Analytics with BigQuery Integration to handle any events that we might need. Aside from some front-end events however we also have some back-end events that trigger once the operation is done with no redirection to the front-end.

What I do is that when the event needs sending, I just send them directly to BigQuery, specifically the intraday table for today since that's where they'll end up anyways, I have around 3 back-end events with this.

The problem is 2 of my backend events go missing when the intraday table converts to a regular table when the next day comes. I know this for sure as yesterday, near the end of the day I quickly whipped up a query to check the number of counts for each of the events. That time there are results, but when the next day comes and I check the regular table (using the same query only changing which table I'm selecting from) and every single instance of the 2 backend events go missing. Leaving me with no data for those events to work with.

Any thoughts why this might be happening?